# What Test of Intelligence can an Emperor use to decide his successor among his three daughter heirs?

Tags: fiction, plot, fantasy, writers-block, subplot

So, I'm writing a piece of fiction where there is a King with three daughters. In order to decide who becomes the next Queen, he sets three trials. Trials of Heart, Mind and Might. I'm done with the first trial and have a good idea about what will happen in the second one.

But try as I might, I can't come up with a test that tests intelligence that is good enough to decide who becomes the next Queen.

I've thought of things like treasure hunts, and a hunt to catch some bandits first or something along those lines. But, is it really realistic to think a King will determine the Kingdom's future by means of a treasure hunt?

For the Heart, I sent a farmer whose crops were destroyed by locusts to each princess to ask for relieve from the year's taxes.

The first one was kind and agreed to allow him to not pay the taxes of that year.

The second one was intelligent and moved, so she allowed him one more year to pay only a quarter of what he should have paid.

The third one is clever and sly, and her spies had already informed her that the farmer was a test. So she also allowed him to not pay that year's tax.

All three passed the Trial of Heart in that way. Obviously, other than the third, none of them knew they were being tested.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe go the Salomon route and pit the three daughters against each other in a way that would tear the country apart, and the first daughter to say "Hey wait, I don't want to destroy my country" gets to rule it?

Comment: It might help to say what the other 2 trials are, so there is some frame of scale for the 3rd…? The intelligence test could be a frame challenge (a sideways solution to an 'impossible' task, like the **Gordian Knot**), unless Heart is already the frame challenge (towr's idea seems more suitable for Heart, imo)… The other possibility is that each princess is meant to win 1 contest, so the frame challenge is in the contest itself (they must support each other, no matter the challenges).

Comment: What have you tried so far and why don't you like it?

Comment: @towr, that was a good idea except I agree with wetcircuit that its better as a heart challenge

Comment: @wetcircuit My plan is for all three to pass all three tests and all be crowned queens and rule collectively. This is just a prologue for a much larger plot I have in mind that includes three queens ruling over an empire

Comment: @NofP I've added what I've thought of so far

Comment: @DarkProgrammer Thanks for the extra info, I was hoping a pattern or theme might emerge that would make the 3 tests 'fit' together – your example sounds interesting plot-wise, but unfortunately without a theme or pattern this question is 'Asking What to Write' which is off-topic as it won't help other writers, and answers will just be random opinions.

Comment: This question is really flirting with the "Asking what to write" line, but I think it's still okay. Don't be surprised if it gets closed, though.

Comment: Have each princess devise a test for the intelligence of the other princesses*.  
The one that thinks of the best test wins.

The benefit of this test is that it will tell the king if his daughters will be good at selecting their advisors and councilors. You can't rule a kingdom by yourself. You need to be able to find good people to delegate responsibilities to.

(*Yes, I realize I just made your problem three times worse.) (Unfortunately the question was just closed, so I'm throwing it here)

Comment: @towr :( yes that just made my problem three times worse but it's a really intriguing idea. Thank you!

Comment: @DWKraus I wasn't actually aware that I couldn't ask for what to write in this exchange :(( I'm mostly a part of the overflow community and just joined this one. It was quite a surprise when I saw it was closed and the reason why it was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would (as an author) invent some historical puzzles, and quiz them on that. Any new Queen should be well versed in politics and strategy at the level of leadership.

For example:

> The true test of a leader, my girls, is not in how you respond in the
> moment, but how you respond after careful thought. That is what I wish
> to test in you.
>
> In my third year as King, Leander to the West tested me, he seized our
> Trilling Wood, from the Halfling Hill on our border all the way to the
> Telos river.
>
> I defended that territory and I built the watchtower on Halfling Hill,
> manned to this day. But looking back, I realized Leander could have
> succeeded. I give you the day I had to consider my actions, A day in
> which I failed to defend against a smart strategy which Leander did
> not pursue.
>
> Roland will provide you with what we knew then; you will be
> sequestered in your rooms. You may call on him at any time to answer
> questions or get his advice, I had that. But he will not provide you
> any hints to the solution. So think on this. Tomorrow morning each of
> you will tell me how Leander should have battled for the Trilling
> Wood.

Stuff like that. I believe that; situations in which a national leader has less than a day to respond are rather few; even repelling an invasion is more at the level of his generals. Plotting the strategy of a war, the generals buy you a day to think about it.

Most intellectual puzzles don't give you hours or days to solve them; they are more tests of quick creative thought; the wrong thing to test in a national leader.

I have this problem myself; I've invented dozens of original solutions to math and CS problems, I've been hired repeatedly as a contractor to do that. But ask me to do that on the spot? Beats me. Give me two uninterrupted weeks to immerse myself in the problem, and there's a very good chance I will figure something out.

If you want to test a leader's intelligence, make sure you are testing the right kind of intelligence. I would invent and write three such story challenges, not necessarily all from their own kingdom.

> In the battle for Goat Island, Commander Zorn made three crucial
> errors, and though victorious, these lost more than half her ships.
> Like Commander Zorn, I grant you six hours to identify her mistakes.
> After dinner, you will each tell me how she could have known better.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a good path to choose. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: You can even look for some real human history historical wartime bungling, and recast those actual strategic errors into cautionary tales within your fictional world. Stuff like Custer's Last Stand. People that **started** wars they then lost (like Hitler, but many have done it; like picked a fight with Israel, got their ass kicked and lost territory to Israel). If these mistakes really happened on Earth, you can probably make them sound plausible in your fictional setting, too.

Comment: I'll probably have to do a lot of research on the scenario I choose but that's better than creating a situation myself and overlooking a giant plot hole or obvious solution. Probably for the best if I look at real history lol. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

## Intelligence AND Loyalty:

Make the test about both intellect and a demonstration of loyalty to the current king. The King tells them this an additional test, and demands that each daughter explain their actions in the other tests, and truthfully. For example:

- The first daughter can tell the truth about the mercy test and appear loyal (or lie because she doesn't trust her father, and claim a clever reason, thus passing the intelligence test but proving disloyal). But truth in this case could be the most intelligent response to a king with many spies.
- The second daughter gives an analysis of the farmer's likelihood of paying back and appears the most intelligent. She does exactly as the King orders, and is thus also loyal.
- The third daughter admits to spying, and thus appears intelligent and loyal when it counts (or lies again, claiming mercy, and appears loyal, but the King knows she used spies).